# if I use "dispatch_semaphore_wait" block never get executed

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch, semaphore, video-processing

I am trying to use semaphore.
 But if I use `dispatch_semaphore_wait()`, block never get executed.
 I checked threads and definitely **waiting thread and signaling thread are different thread.**
First I tried Following code.

```
dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
AVVideoComposition *videoComposition = [AVVideoComposition videoCompositionWithAsset:self.selectedVideo applyingCIFiltersWithHandler:^(AVAsynchronousCIImageFilteringRequest * _Nonnull request) {
     CIImage *filteredImage = [CIImage CIFilterCustomLUTFilter:request.sourceImage CustomLUTFilter:self.filterArray[indexPath.row]];

     [request finishWithImage:filteredImage context:nil];
     NSLog(@"signal here %@", [NSThread currentThread]);
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
}];

    NSLog(@"wait here %@", [NSThread currentThread]);
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    self.playerLayer.player.currentItem.videoComposition = videoComposition;

    AVAssetExportSession *export = [AVAssetExportSession exportSessionWithAsset:self.selectedVideo presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];
    export.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
    export.videoComposition = videoComposition;
    NSString *savingPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/video.mov", NSTemporaryDirectory()];
    export.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:savingPath];

    [export exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
        UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(savingPath, nil, nil, nil);
    }];
});
```

What I am trying to do here is waitting result of `applyCIFilterWithHandler` before exporting video.
But In this way, main thread is blocked and App falls into deadlock situation.

**First Question. Can't I use `dispatch_semaphore_wait()` on main thread? even if waiting thread and signaling thread are different each other?**

After I tried Following code

```
dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
AVVideoComposition *videoComposition = [AVVideoComposition videoCompositionWithAsset:self.selectedVideo applyingCIFiltersWithHandler:^(AVAsynchronousCIImageFilteringRequest * _Nonnull request) {
     CIImage *filteredImage = [CIImage CIFilterCustomLUTFilter:request.sourceImage CustomLUTFilter:self.filterArray[indexPath.row]];

     [request finishWithImage:filteredImage context:nil];
     NSLog(@"signal here %@", [NSThread currentThread]);
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
}];

dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("myQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{
    NSLog(@"wait here %@", [NSThread currentThread]);
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    self.playerLayer.player.currentItem.videoComposition = videoComposition;

    AVAssetExportSession *export = [AVAssetExportSession exportSessionWithAsset:self.selectedVideo presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];
    export.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
    export.videoComposition = videoComposition;
    NSString *savingPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/video.mov", NSTemporaryDirectory()];
    export.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:savingPath];

    [export exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
        UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(savingPath, nil, nil, nil);
    }];
});
```

Everything is same but I make my custom thread to wait signal. But this time also, block never get executed. though my App didn't fall into deadlock...(Of course,, I didn't block main thread this time)

**Second Question. How can I implement semaphore here properly?**

I will be really appreciate if you don't just say **'just use `dispatch_group` instead!'**. Of course, It's very nice to give another options to implement same thing though. then, please give me both way to implement with semaphore and dispatch_group.

Thanks very much!

**Another Try**

I tried to implement this with `dispatch_group` and `dispatch_group_notify`, but still the `applyCIFilterWithHandler` block is never called.(it is called definitely when there is no such things like dispatch_group, semaphore.

this is code implemented by 1dispatch_group`and`dispatch_group_notify`

```
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

dispatch_group_enter(group);
AVVideoComposition *videoComposition = [AVVideoComposition videoCompositionWithAsset:self.selectedVideo applyingCIFiltersWithHandler:^(AVAsynchronousCIImageFilteringRequest * _Nonnull request) {
    CIImage *filteredImage = [CIImage CIFilterCustomLUTFilter:request.sourceImage CustomLUTFilter:self.filterArray[indexPath.row]];

    [request finishWithImage:filteredImage context:nil];
    NSLog(@"block done here %@", [NSThread currentThread]);
    dispatch_group_leave(group);
}];

dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSLog(@"start saving here %@", [NSThread currentThread]);
    self.playerLayer.player.currentItem.videoComposition = videoComposition;

    AVAssetExportSession *export = [AVAssetExportSession exportSessionWithAsset:self.selectedVideo presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];
    export.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
    export.videoComposition = videoComposition;
    NSString *savingPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/video.mov", NSTemporaryDirectory()];
    export.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:savingPath];

    [export exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
        UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(savingPath, nil, nil, nil);
    }];
});
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `dispatch_semaphore_wait` on the main thread, as it will block the main thread, which is never a good idea.  The simpler approach is just to move the code that you want to execute after the composition has completed into its own method and simply invoke that method from the completion block.  You could also use a `dispatch_group` with `dispatch_group_notify`

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks to reply, but I tried dispatch_group with dispatch_group_notifiy approach. It didn't work either.

Comment: As I said,  I can't see why you really need either approach, simply do what you need in the completion handler block

Comment: @Paulw11 cause, i wanna know how dispatch things work.

Comment: I can't see any issue with your `dispatch_group` code

Comment: Are you trying to do that when clicking a table cell or a button inside a table cell? Because I was able to trigger the handler before exporting but is just working with a non inside table cell button, if I try executing the function when clicking a table cell, it won't work, I don't know why.